# Am not able to create database with custom sqlite bindings

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I custom Built Sqlite For android studio.
To be able to store polygon coordinates.

But running my code it produces the error

> Caused by: org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database

When triying to getReadableDatabase();

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity

    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private  TestOpenHelper mOpenHelper;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    System.loadLibrary("sqliteX");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mOpenHelper = new TestOpenHelper(this);

    mOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
```

> TestOpenHelper class

```
import  org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;;
import org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class TestOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "test.db";
public static final int DaATABASE_VERISION = 1;
public TestOpenHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DaATABASE_VERISION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(TestDatabaseContract.OwnerInfoEntry.SQL_CREATE_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(TestDatabaseContract.PropertyInfoEntry.SQL_CREATE_TABLE);


    DatabaseDataWorker worker = new DatabaseDataWorker(db);
    worker.insertOwnerInfo();
    worker.insertPropertyInfo();


}
```

> DatabaseCoontract Class

```
import android.provider.BaseColumns;


public final class TestDatabaseContract {
private TestDatabaseContract() {}

public static  final class  PropertyInfoEntry {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "property_info";
    public static  final String COLUMN_PROPERTY_ID = "property_id";

    public  static final String SQL_CREATE_TABLE =
            "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " USING geopoly(" + COLUMN_PROPERTY_ID  +  ")";
}
public static  final class OwnerInfoEntry implements  BaseColumns{
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "owner_info";
    public static  final String COLUMN_OWNER_ID = "id";
    public static  final String COLUMN_OWNER_NAME = "name";
    public static  final String COLUMN_OWNER_LOCATION = "location";
    public static  final String COLUMN_PROPERTY_ID = "property_id";

    public  static final String SQL_CREATE_TABLE =
            "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                    _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                    COLUMN_OWNER_ID + " INTEGER UNIQUE NOT NULL, " +
                    COLUMN_OWNER_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    COLUMN_OWNER_LOCATION + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    COLUMN_PROPERTY_ID + " TEXT)";
}
```

}

Comment: Try to provoide storage permission i.e android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: I see you are opening the database in readOnly mode writing will fail, can you replace getReadbleDatabase with getWritableDatabase

Comment: I did provide storage permision.

Comment: Same Error When i change it to getWritable "

Comment: FYI, Database has not yet been created at this point

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17034511/android-database-sqlite-sqlitecantopendatabaseexception-unknown-error-code-14

Comment: @AlexHart, Thanks but have seen it and non of the solutions proposed work out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem and i solved it with the solution CL provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26642797/android-custom-sqlite-build-cannot-open-database)